# spool sql log with the date on name

Tags: windows, oracle, spool

I have the sql script at the beginning I put:

```
column dt new_value mydate noprint
select to_char(sysdate. 'YYYYMMDD') dt from dual;
spool &mydate.test.log
```

try to spool the log with the timestamp.

However, when I do this, the spool out file name like &mydate.test.log

Anyone has idea of what I've missed here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

In SQL*Plus, check the `define` setting with

```
show define
```

Normally, that should give something like

```
define "&" (hex 26)
```

however, it is possible to set it to a different character, or disable it altogether, in which case you would see

```
define OFF
```

and to re-enable it you would need to

```
set define on
```

If you want to retain the `.` between the date and `test.log`, you will need two dots, as the first one terminates the substitution variable:

```
SQL> spool &mydate..test.log
SQL> spool
currently spooling to 20180830.test.log
```

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
SET define ON
```

For example:

```
SQL> column dt new_value mydate noprint
SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDD') dt from dual;

SQL> set define off
SQL> select '&mydate' from dual;

'&MYDATE'
--------------------------------
&mydate

SQL> set define on
SQL> select '&mydate' from dual;

'20180830'
--------------------------------
20180830
```

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG073) you find something more.